# Why is the inherent error in measurement of position of particle of the order of $\frac{\lambda}{2}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, error-analysis

The setup is : To measure the position of a moving particle, we send a light beam and we calculate the time required ($t_0$) for the light to travel to the particle, reflect and come back.
we can use the equation $x_0 = \frac{ct_0}{2}$.
By measuring the delay in the arrival time of the reflected wave, there seems to be an inherent error of the order of $\frac{\lambda}{2}$. Why is that so?

Comment: Possibly a diffraction effect but more details are needed as to the setup and how the statement *there seems to be an inherent error of the order of $\lambda/2$* was arrived at.

Comment: @Farcher especially since it should be $\frac{\lambda^2}{4\pi\Delta\lambda}$

Comment: This is because of an effect called dufraction limit . see. https://sassafras13.github.io/DiffractionLimit/

Comment: There is no "inherent" error in position measurement. The precision only depends on the resolution of the detector system and can be made arbitrarily small (at least in theory, in practice we are limited by accelerator beam energy). The more important thing to realize is that nature conserves energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges but not "position", i.e. the physically relevant properties of quantum systems are very poorly served by focus on a classical position measurement that nature simply does not care about.